# how to get bundle id of commandline tool

Tags: ios, macos, unix

I have created a command line tool long back using Xcode6.2. Now i forgot that tool bundle identifier, is there a way to get cmdline tool identifier from the built binary?

In xcode6.2 there is no such option to view the bundle identifier of cmdline tool.

Comment: you mean from the built binary, not from the source Xcode project?

Comment: Yep i guess thats the only way as per my knowledge. In xcode there is no such option to see bundle id of cmdline tool.

Answer (score 5):

**If** the command-line tool has an embedded Info.plist, which is not typical, you can view it using:

```
otool -P <path to executable>
```

The bundle ID would be one of the keys in that Info.plist.

Other than an embedded Info.plist, stand-alone binaries don't really have bundle IDs.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what is in <path to executable>? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** You can't. Err... kinda.

A command line tool does not have a bundle identifier *by default*. For what it's worth, you can try looking at the `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` setting in **Build Settings**.

However, if you're asking about obtaining the bundle identifier at runtime (provided you have an `Info.plist` file being embedded, as noted by @trojanfoe in the comments), you can obtain it via:

```
[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier
```

Comment: But i remember while creating, it was showing the expected bundle identifier. eg:com.companyname.appname

Comment: if i have source or gonna build new binary then i can try whatever you suggesting. But now what i need is, how to find a bundle id from the built binary file?

Comment: Not true: see [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html) on embedding an `Info.plist` file containing a bundle identifier into a single-file executable.

Comment: @trojanfoe: That's why I specifically mentioned "by default".

Comment: You said "You can't".  That isn't true.